# Is there a way to shutdown the computer after defrag with the builtin Windows 7 defrag tool?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, defragment

I don't like running defrag when I use the computer, so I want to start it before going to bed and let it do its work and have it shut down the computer when it's done.

I haven't find an option for it in the builtin defrag tool. I know 3rd party defraggers can shut down the machine after finishing, but I don't want to install an other program just for that.

Is there a way to do that with the builtin defragger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to create a batch file that runs the defrag and then issues the shutdown command on your PC, no?

Create a batch file that looks something like:

```
DEFRAG C: /U /V
SHUTDOWN /s /t 00
```